# How do i use Lodash to Sort by attributes of an children array

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

```
 - const Employers=[
           {employerName:"A1",employees:[{employeeName:"EA1"},{employeeName:"EA2"}]},
           {employerName:"B1",employees:[{employeeName:"EB1"},{employeeName:"EB2"}]}
           ]
```

my question how do i sort employers by employeeName.

Comment: @MarioSantini the accepted answer uses ``_.pluck`` which has been removed from *lodash*

Comment: With @MarioSantini suggestion, you should be able to get further and make this a better question.

Comment: its a not a duplicate question , the link mentioned is completely different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sort by first from sorted employees

```
_.sortBy(Employers, function(emp) {
    return _.chain(emp)
        .get('employees')
        .sortBy('employeeName')
        .map('employeeName')
        .first()
        .value();
});
```

Comment: This doesnt work ..

Comment: @Kamaraju check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/stasovlas/wLoo1rbb/

Comment: I think you modified bit it seems , let me check

Comment: @Kamaraju I dont modifed anything

Comment: Intially you had additional variable sort appended to the object ..

Comment: @Kamaraju yes, sorry, i think you dont see it

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the data-structure, I would recommend going with this:

```
const EmployersSortable = [
  { employerName: 'A1', employeeName: 'EA1' },
  { employerName: 'B1', employeeName: 'EB2' },
  { employerName: 'A1', employeeName: 'EA2' },
  { employerName: 'B1', employeeName: 'EB1' }
]
```

Then you can just do: `EmployersSortable = _.sortBy(EmployersSortable, 'employeeName');`

If you can't change the data-structure, then you'll have to iterate through the original one and convert it to the above one by doing this:

```
var EmployersSortable = [];

Employers.forEach(function(employerObj) {
  employerObj.employees.forEach(function(employeeObj) {
    EmployersSortable.push({
      employerName: employerObj.employerName,
      employeeName: employeeObj.employeeName
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: I dont think its good option to breakdown the structure and again reconstruct the structure for sort